# How to get wordpress navigation to work

Tags: menus, navigation

I have been using this code to display my wordpress navigation and it worked;

```
<ul id="menu">
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

However,i want to use register_nav_menus so that i can arrange my menus from the wp backend.I have this code and its not working as expected;

```
<?php
      wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu',
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
    )
      );
?>
```

My menus html should looks like this

```
    <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="http://localhost">Home</a></li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Pages</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>   
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Admin UI</a>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Features</a>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Shortcodes Wp 3.3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sliders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Columns</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sliders</a>
                    <ul>    
                    <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sliders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Columns</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Columns</a></li>
                </ul>               
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Cute</a>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `...and its not working as expected` — what exactly did you expect and what is it doing otherwise? could you edit your question and clarify that?

Comment: I expected my ul to have the id menu.I looked at the function on codex and discovered the menu_id parameter.Its now working well.I shall answer the question after 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main menu' ));
```

Make sure you have a menu called 'Main menu'

Comment: This worked for me - <?php $defaults = array(
 
  'menu_id'         => 'menu',
  'echo'            => true,
  'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu'
  );
?>

<?php wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>

Comment: @flapjack Plz delete the comment and write your own answer, so that we can upvote and you can mark it as the answer after 2 days. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
<?php $defaults = array( 'menu_id' => 'menu', 'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu' ); ?>

 <?php wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
```

I was missing the `'menu_id' => 'menu' id`.